# How to get a column-wise min of list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[9, -2], 
     [8, 7], 
     [9, 100]]
```

I'm expecting the output of `min(a)` to be `[8, -2]`.

But the actual output of `min(a)` is `[8, 7]`

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because `[8, -2]` is not present in `a`.  If you want the minimum of each sub-element, that's a different question.

Comment: Using plain python you will need to do something like: `[min(col) for col in  zip(*a)]`. Numpy makes it a bit shorter: `numpy.min(a, axis=0)`

Comment: @Mark or `a.min(axis=0)` or shorter `a.min(0)`, if `a` is `np.ndarray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min(a)` will give you the smallest row, performing a row by row comparison.  You get [8,7] because [8,7] is smaller than [9,-2] and smaller than [9,100] (compared as whole lists).

If you want the minimum of each column independently, you can use zip to access column values and apply the min() function to each column:

```
[*map(min,zip(*a))]  # [8, -2]
```

Answer (score 2):

`min()` finds the smallest element in the sequence. `[8, -2]` is not in the sequence, so that can't be the answer.

`[8, 7]` has the smallest *first element*, so it is the minimum.